# C# - Get property of Attribute with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, attributes

I have a Attribute which has properties itself. I would like to access one of These properties (a boolean) and check whether it's true or not. I was able to check whether the Attribute is set, but thats about all .. at least with linq.

Attribute:

```
public class ImportParameter : System.Attribute
{
    private Boolean required;

    public ImportParameter(Boolean required)
    {
        this.required = required;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
    [ImportParameter(false)]
    public long AufgabeOID { get; set; }
```

What I have so far:

```
        var properties = type.GetProperties()
            .Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(ImportParameter)))
            .Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

I played around a Little, but I don't seem to be able to verify whether the property required is set or not.

Comment: `required` seems to be a field, not a property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all if you want to access the required field you need to make it public, better a public property:

```
public class ImportParameter : System.Attribute
{
  public Boolean Required {get; private set;}

  public ImportParameter(Boolean required)
  {
      this.Required = required;
  }
}
```

then you can use this query Linq to search for properties that have the Required attribute set to false:

```
var properties = type.GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes() //get all attributes of this property
                         .OfType<ImportParameter>() // of type ImportParameter
                         .Any(a=>a.Required == false)) //that have the Required property set to false
            .Select(p => p.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to make the required property public, like

```
public class ImportParameter : System.Attribute
{
  public Boolean Required {get; private set;}

  public ImportParameter(Boolean required)
  {
      this.Required = required;
  }
}
```

Now you should be able to access your attributes object.

Notice that by using `public <DataType> <Name> {get; private set;}` your property is accessible as public, but can only be set private.

Following a complete working example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    [ImportParameter(false)]
    public Foo fc {get;set;}

    public static void Main()
    {       
        var required = typeof(Program).GetProperties()
            .SelectMany(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                          .OfType<ImportParameter>()
                          .Select(x => new { p.Name, x.Required }))
            .ToList();

        required.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("PropertyName: " + x.Name + " - Required: " + x.Required));
    }
}

public class ImportParameter : System.Attribute
{
  public Boolean Required {get; private set;}

  public ImportParameter(Boolean required)
  {
      this.Required = required;
  }
}

public class Foo 
{
    public String Test = "Test";
}
```