# Select only members in anonymous with a certain attribute

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-function

I have a class named `Employee` (this is only part of it):

```
public class Employee
{        
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Place { get; set; }

    [IncludeinReport]
    public string BusinessVertical { get; set; }

    [IncludeinReport]
    public string Region { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }

    [IncludeinReport]
    public string BusinessUnit { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use Linq to only pick the properties that have the `IncludeinReport` attribute. Below is the linq I have now, all I'm doing is just *manually picking* the properties with the attribute:

```
                 var report = from c in Employee                
                 orderby c.Region, c.BusinessUnit
                 select new
                 {
                     c.BusinessVertical,
                     c.Region,
                     c.BusinessUnit,
                 }
```

But I want to be able to do something like this:

```
                 var report = from c in Employee                
                 orderby c.Region, c.BusinessUnit
                 select c.members.hasattribute(IncludeinReport)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Get property of Attribute with Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922161/c-sharp-get-property-of-attribute-with-linq)

Comment: How would you use (elements of) `report` ?  You are asking for something that is runtime dynamic. You will have to look at the attributes (or derived info) again in the report engine.

Comment: How are you going to use the result? For example, if it's something which is going to be used as a model for a template engine like T4, or an MVC View (WebForms View Engine, Razor, ...) or be shown in a `DataGridView` in Windows Forms, then relying on some standard attributes like `Browsable` would be enough. You can also extend those frameworks to be able to rely on your custom attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure if this is the best way, but you could do the following.

Object

```
public class Employee
{        
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Place { get; set; }

    [IncludeinReport]
    public string BusinessVertical { get; set; }

    [IncludeinReport]
    public string Region { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }

    [IncludeinReport]
    public string BusinessUnit { get; set; }
}

public class IncludeinReport:Attribute
{
}
```

Sample Data

```
var list = new List<Employee>
    {
        new Employee{ID = 1, Region = "Europe", BusinessUnit="Software", BusinessVertical = "Sample1"},
        new Employee{ID = 1, Region = "Asia", BusinessUnit="Software", BusinessVertical = "Sample1"},
        new Employee{ID = 1, Region = "Asia", BusinessUnit="Hardware", BusinessVertical = "Sample1"},
        new Employee{ID = 1, Region = "Europe", BusinessUnit="Software", BusinessVertical = "Sample1"},
        new Employee{ID = 1, Region = "Asia", BusinessUnit="Telecom", BusinessVertical = "Sample1"},
        new Employee{ID = 1, Region = "Europe", BusinessUnit="Software", BusinessVertical = "Sample1"},
    };
```

For above, you could query as follows. You need to fetch properties that have the required attribute. This list of Properties is used in your query on data. And finally, you make use of ExpandoObject to create the required type.

```
var properties =  typeof(Employee).GetProperties().Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(IncludeinReport))).Select(v=>v);
var intermediate = list.OrderBy(c => c.Region).ThenBy(x=>x.BusinessUnit).SelectMany((x,index)=> properties.Select(v=> new {GroupId = index, Dict = new KeyValuePair<string,object>(v.Name, v.GetValue(x))})) ;
var resultList = new List<ExpandoObject>();

 foreach(var item in intermediate.GroupBy(x=>x.GroupId))
 {
    resultList.Add(CreateObject(item.ToList().Select(x=>x.Dict)));
 }
```

Where CreateObject is defined as

```
ExpandoObject CreateObject(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,object>> kvps)
{
    dynamic returnValue = new ExpandoObject();
    var dict = returnValue as IDictionary<string, object>;
    foreach (var kvp in kvps)
    {
        dict.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Output

[image]

**Update**

You could use an Extension method for CreateObject, which would make it bit for readable.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static ExpandoObject CreateObject(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,object>> source)
    {
        dynamic returnValue = new ExpandoObject();
        var dict = returnValue as IDictionary<string, object>;
        foreach (var kvp in source)
        {
            dict.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

After which, the query becomes.

```
var properties =  typeof(Employee).GetProperties().Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(IncludeinReport))).Select(v=>v);
var intermediate = list.OrderBy(c => c.Region).ThenBy(x=>x.BusinessUnit).SelectMany((x,index)=> properties.Select(v=> new {GroupId = index, Dict = new KeyValuePair<string,object>(v.Name, v.GetValue(x))})) ;
var resultList = intermediate.GroupBy(x=>x.GroupId).Select(x=>x.ToList().Select(c=>c.Dict).CreateObject());
```